# chat instead of question and instead of cross-posting

Tags: discussion

There were two chat messages this morning (my time) that left me wondering what to do.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12630095#12630095[image]

On the first beg (Williams) I responded only to find that the person did not post a question as requested even after urging.

To the second (captain) I did not respond, to me this is like cross posting and if I would have been mentioned (@Anthon) out of the blue in a chat like this, I would probably have given my opinion about what I think about begging and that I would look at questions if I had time and were on a site I frequent (I can be very unsubtle, I have practised that a lot).

I think my handling of Williams was OK, but I am not sure if this encouraged others to start begging on chat and how to put a stop to it (if necessary).

Should I have reacted differently? Should I have complained to Captain, or is this, what I call begging, ok on chat.

Answer (score 7):

I always keep this thought in the back of my mind: *If a user doesn't want to put the time in to write up their questions, then why should one of us be willing to help?*

---

If it's their first time asking a question in chat, and I'm feeling like helping, I'll begin helping them their (sometimes) but often am trying to direct them to the main site where they should ask their question so that more people can see it.

If it's their second or third time (which it is for Williams) then I'll often times just ignore them in the chat room or remind them **without** offering any help in the chat room. (Mainly because I do not want to encourage the bad behavior of asking questions in the chat room, or reward it.

There is a small group of users that think they should ask their questions in the chat room or will post a question and then 2 seconds later start hounding regulars asking if they'd seen their question yet. To these users I would continuously remind them of the rules of the site and that people are here of *their* own accord, and hounding them for help will often times have the opposite effect.

I read your interaction with both and thought you handled it fine. I certainly wouldn't recommend that anyone work an entire problem in chat. It happens from time to time, but if it's the same users asking for the help, and you've told them numerous times to ask their question on the main site and they don't, I would simply ignore their requests in chat...hopefully they'll get the message.

Comment: I'd say it's ok to talk in chat but only if you've _already_ posted on main and are moving a long discussion out of the comments **and** link back to it later.  or just, you know, use the "please avoid extended discussions in chat" link.

Comment: @strugee - I'd relax it just a bit more and say if you're new to the site and you're not sure if something is Q worthy you can ask, but this should only be 1-2 times per visitor to the site, and only if you're new or have never asked a Q before. Otherwise what you said applies 100% of the time, IMO.

Comment: that's a good question though. would we rather have people "try it out" and see if a question they're on the fence with works, or would we rather have people be more conservative? (maybe deserving of another meta question)

Comment: @strugee - go for it and ask. I'd prefer them ask in the chat, but it shouldn't digress into solving it there, only if it's worthy.